# Automatically create a Wordpress gallery on a specific post from a Dropbox account

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, dropbox

I'm working on a Wordpress project where a client would like to automatically create a new image gallery in a post by adding a new folder of images to a Dropbox account.

[image: The image link is the simplest explanation I can generate.]

The posts will be a custom post-type and the ***Brand*** of store will be a category within custom taxonomies.The images will be pre-sized before upload so no need for cropping functionality. Gallery of thumbs clicking through to a lightbox.

If it is simpler to remove Dropbox from the equation and work directly with server directories, this would also work. I will sync the Dropbox account to the server directories separately.

I'm fairly new to PHP scripts (although always happy to learn) but in an ideal world any scripts would need to execute every 5 minutes to ensure content is continuously up-to-date.

Any advice, thoughts, suggestions, comments or solutions would be greatly appreciated.